# Displaying a menu on a Pushpin click event (WP7 + Bing maps)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, pushpin

I have set up Pushpins onto a map and have set coordinates and text for each.
What I want is to be able to display a menu of some kind when the user taps the pushpin. 
The menu would display an option for accessing the website(every pushpin points to a cinema), the phone number would be displayed and an option for displaying directions.

I've set up the pushpins and then set up my click event like this:

```
void PushPin_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("you clicked!");

            var pushpin = sender as Pushpin;


        }
```

I think I can use the pushpin variable then to control the content etc.

But how do I display a menu with click-able options??

Comment: That's complex. Check this blog post and the referenced coding4fun toolkit http://shirjaushii.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/creating-pushpin-floating-menu-in-windows-phone-application-using-panorama-and-messageprompt/

Comment: thank you. that seems great but any chance you've used it? I can't see how to add anything but images and text.

Comment: nevermind..i figured it out. This seems like it could work perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ContextMenu from Silverlight toolkit and show it when user clicks on a pushpin. See http://igrali.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/show-a-tooltip-for-tapped-pushpin-on-windows-phone/